# Foundation for Emails Node.js TypeError

Tags: node.js, gulp, zurb-foundation

I am having this issue
[TypeError][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEIf7.png

When I run `foundation watch` it gives me the error `TypeError: execute is not a function`

I have reinstalled foundation, node, npm and gulp but still getting the same error.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: code for what exactly?

Comment: Well, I'm slightly confused about what your TypeError is; how are you getting an error for an image link?